# Compilation hangs for a class with field double d = 2.2250738585072012e-308

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have come across an interesting situation. A coworker committed some changes, which would not compile on my machine neither from the IDE (Eclipse) nor from a command line (Maven). The problem manifested in the compilation process taking 100% CPU and only killing the process would help to stop it. After some analysis the cause of the problem was located and resolved. It turned out be a line "double d = 2.2250738585072012e-308" (without semicolon at the end) in one of the interfaces. The following snipped duplicates it.

```
public class WeirdCompilationIssue {
   double d = 2.2250738585072012e-308
}
```

Why would compiler hang? A language edge case?

Comment: By the way: it shouldn't matter if there is a semicolon after the number or not. It's the numeric value of the `double` literal that's the problem.

Comment: The same happens in Intellij IDEA. Must be a SDK bug.

Comment: Googling for 2.2250738585072012e-308 would have given you plenty of answers.

Comment: Throw with an Exception at your coworker!

Comment: @Peter: the `javac` command line compiler in the Oracle JDK/OpenJDK has the same problem: the underlying JVM itself has the bug.

Comment: Aparrently this has been a reported bug for 10 years. Itshas been a bug in other languages too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bug in the String-to-double conversion algorithm of the JVM: http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/

You can get the same hang if you try to parse that string at runtime. The compiler hangs because it uses the same code (it's a Java program after all).

*Update:* the issue now has a [CVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures) identifier ([CVE-2010-4476](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-4476)) and [a patch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alert-cve-2010-4476-305811.html) (for Oracle JVMs, also works on OpenJDK).

According to [the patch](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2011-February/005795.html) it all boils down to an off-by-one error.

Comment: It is even a security issue (denial of server) when a service accepts JSON. Sending a json document like : {x: 2.2250738585072012e-308} to a web resource which is expecting a JSON document will hang on parse.

Comment: This co-worker is a really funny guy... Nice way to kill a build.

Comment: @Andreas_D: oh yes, in case it wasn't obvious: chances are you co-worker did *not* accidentally check in that number.

Comment: I hope he did that accidentally -- he has a habit of turning off the automatic compilation in Eclipse (:

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue which was in news a couple of days back. More info [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/).

Answer (score 3):

This is an open bug for over 10 years. Bad Sun.

The fact that Java systems haven't been attacked and dead in masses proves that there are really very few naughty people on the earth.

Comment: Imagine if it happened in a nuclear reactor :D But then, you wouldn't use Java for that. Maybe for the control systems.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has released a hot fix which can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/fpupdater-tool-readme-305936.html

The hotfix will work for java 1.4, 1.5, and 1.6.