# Program hangs while parsing Double value?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compilation hangs for a class with field double d = 2.2250738585072012e-308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895857/compilation-hangs-for-a-class-with-field-double-d-2-2250738585072012e-308)

Why does this Java program hang while parsing a double value `0.0222507385850720119e-00306`?

```
public class DoubleTest {

  public static boolean isDoubleValue(String value) {
    try {
      Double.valueOf(value);
      return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }


  public static void main(String a[]){

    DoubleTest.isDoubleValue("0.0222507385850720119e-306");
    System.out.println("out of hang...");
  }

}
```

Comment: I assume you're aware this is a Java bug that was fixed by Oracle a year ago?

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: It works on my JVM of version 1.6.0_26.

Comment: +1 to you. Bingo! @Bloodwolf it works for me in JDK 1.6.0_26 too. i was using JDK 1.6.0_16 earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hang for me. The following program works fine in Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1):

```
class Test {
    public static double isDoubleValue(String value) {
        try {
            double d = Double.valueOf(value);
            return d;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        double d = Test.isDoubleValue("0.0222507385850720119e-306");
        System.out.println("out of hang... " + d);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
out of hang... 2.2250738585072014E-308
```

as expected.

I will mention that the -308 exponent is right at the edge of permissible double values so it may be a bug in your particular Java version. However, it doesn't exist in Indigo, as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! @paxdiablo. the actual reason is the issue with jdk i was using.(1.6.0_16)

Comment: @selvakumar.esra, there's usually not a compelling reason not to be running the most recent bugfix version of a release. I'd suggest upgrading to 1.6.0_<max> at least.